# How to structure react preload utility code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I’m currently learning React after spending years working with vanilla JS and jQuery.

I need to preload some web fonts, and in future maybe images, audio, video etc… anything really. This question could relate to any number of utilities that need performing before something is rendered on screen.

I approached this the way I always have - load stuff, then set a var that I can use to determine what content renders (in this case the var is set in a Redux store).

My preload.js code is as follows:

```
import WebFont from 'webfontloader';
import store from 'js/store/store';
WebFont.load({
  custom: {
    families: ['MyCustomFont']
  },
  active: function(){
    store.dispatch.data.setPreloadedFonts();
  }
});
```

My index.js app code can be simplified as:

```
import preload from './preload';
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if(
      this.props.preloadedFonts &&
      this.props.ajaxDataLoaded &&
      this.props.miscOtherStuffDone
    ){
      return (
        <div>
          <Switch>
            // My app routes here…
          </Switch>
        </div>
      )
    }else{
      return (
        <div className="preloader"></div>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

This all works perfectly, is easy and uses very little code.

However, React gives me a warning: 'preload' is defined but never used - no-unused-vars

I understand why this is happening - “preload” must be imported, but is not actively used within the component. From reading around and looking at some other plugins, my guess is that this isn’t the “React way” of doing things, and that my preloader should be in the form of a component that wraps my app - e.g `<Preloader></Preloader>`

Is there a particular way I should approach something like this? It feels like any alternative approach is probably going to be more complicated and less flexible.

Comment: why does preload need to be imported?

Comment: @dynamo it surely has to be imported somewhere, else it won’t run?

Comment: I don't think you need to. try if it works by removing it. I can also look at the whole code if you share it.